# How to automate export file from the application in the firefox browser using selenium and Java?

Tags: selenium

I want to Automate the Export functionality using selenium & java, Export functionality working as per following steps,

Steps:

1. click on Export button.
2. Browser will pop up with Save and cancel.
3. Need to save it to desktop.

Any idea suggest, thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Init the FF driver to save the downloaded file automatically without showing the Save dialog.

Let's assume your exported file is in csv format:

C#

```
// get Desktop path    
string reportFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

// create FF profile    
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv");
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",reportFolder);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

// navigate to the page
// find the export element and click
```